# Google Maps "View Mode" like in Ingress game

Tags: android, google-maps, game-engine

Honestly I'm new in Android Apps Development. but i'm really curious with [Ingress Game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticproject.ingress&hl=en) That Made by Niantic Labs and i want to know what **kind of "view mode"** on Google Maps API/SDK that used in the game? I thought it was 3D view mode but it don't have the Current Location icon like in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngs6S.png) and its not moving when our position moving too.

or maybe is there any map engine or map api/sdk beside google maps android api?

Comment: you can hide that button if you want

Comment: they developed something completely custom, libraries for opengl libgx or something similar... that's why it eats battery

Comment: Also remember that Ingress started at Google so they probably have access to non-public map data (like for making the 3D building a different color)

Comment: @tyczj what button and what view mode is that?

Comment: @NDorigatti i think i start with the maps engine first, then the interface hehe

Comment: @MorrisonChang i know but is there any way to make apps similar like that? or any map engine like its routing but free roam?